# Example of polynomial function satisfying convexity conditions

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

and thank you for your help! I encountered the following problem in my research, and I'm looking for your help / advice:

Find an example of a polynomial function $f: \mathbb R \mapsto \mathbb R$ with the following properties:

i. $ f(0) = f(1) = 0$

ii. $ f'(0) = f'(1) = 0$

iii. $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \in (0, 1)$

iv. $f$ is convex in $[0, 1]$

Remarks:

1. So far, I was able to find an example of a sixth degree function satisfying conditions i, ii, iii, but not iv: $ f(x) = x^3(x^3-3x+2)$

Comment: Conditions (i) and (iii) prevent the function from being convex on $[0,1]$, indeed, a convex function must satisfy $$f(1/2) = f((1/2)0 + (1/2)1) \leq (1/2)f(0) +(1/2)f(1)=0$$

Comment: Even dropping (i) and (iii), the only such polynomials are the constant polynomials. If $f$ is convex on $[0, 1]$, then the derivative must be monotone increasing, so condition (ii) implies that $f'(x) = 0$ for $x \in [0, 1]$. As $f'$ is a polynomial, and has infinitely many roots, it must be the $0$ function, hence $f$ is a constant. Adding in (i) makes it the $0$ polynomial.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense! How about a degree two polynomial $ f:\mathbb R^2 \mapsto \mathbb R$ with the following properties: i. $f(0, 1) = f(1, 0) = 0$ ii. In the set $ S =  \{x, y \in [0, 1] | x+y =1\}$, $f$ is maximized at $(0, 1)$ or $(1, 0)$ iii. f is convex in $S$ ? (this what I actually care about, and was hoping to make $f(x, y)$ have the form  $g(x) + g(y)$ for some polynomial $g$.

Comment: @user35083 Did you mean "minimised" instead of "maximised"?

Comment: yes, sorry! I mean "minimized"!

Comment: Actually, by convexity, I believe that $f(a, 1-a) = f(0, 1) = f(1, 0)$, so f would have to be constant on $S$.. thanks for helping me figure this out!